# What is the best way of removing the ripple-effect in MDriven Turnkey?

Tags: mdriven

Most elements in MDriven Turnkey have a class called `ripple-effect`. How do I remove that class from all elements?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to remove it?

You don't like the ripple look and feel?

Comment: Yes, I also want ro remove the ripple effect. That is not the question, Question is how?

Comment: If there is no built in way we can remove it with javascript. In another thread I ask if there's a customizable javascript hook that runs at page load that I can use, but I don't think so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61774890/is-there-a-page-load-hook-in-mdriven-turnkey

Comment: Is you have a VS project with turnkey, you can change whatever you want. Just remove the ripple.js file from the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the ripple effect by any built in means.