# Is there a page load hook in MDriven Turnkey?

Tags: mdriven

Is there a customizable javascript hook in MDriven Turnkey that gets called on each page load? If not, how do I add such a hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you find the answer here: [MDriven wiki](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/AppWideAngularScriptIncludes)

Comment: Excellent - that's it! Your link is broken, but here is the full link: https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/AppWideAngularScriptIncludes

Answer (score 0):

It's AngularJS. Look at AngularJS to find out how you run JS when page loads.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView#event-$viewContentLoaded

https://azizsaboor.wordpress.com/2015/11/26/angularjs-event-to-call-after-loading/